# crash report from user - app crashing on latest phone

Tags: ios, crash-reports

our app is crashing for users with the latest Iphones The Xr and EXR. One of them sent me a crash report which I could not copy and paste here - so I put it in a Google Doc and turned sharing on.

Here is a link to a google doc with the crash report.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jtR6m0gDM7Kbef9Fd57KoJ9E5ufxl3a7UPSAx-KYrFA/edit?usp=sharing

The abort section looks like this:

```
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x00000001059d8436   x2: 0x0000000108a80470   x3: 0xfffffffffffffff1
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000108a58000   x7: 0x0000000000000bd0
    x8: 0x00000001050cb6e8   x9: 0x0000000108a6c000  x10: 0x00000001050cb6e8  x11: 0x5841472f73656c64
   x12: 0x5841472f73656c64  x13: 0x622e746e65696c43  x14: 0x41472f656c646e75  x15: 0x00746e65696c4358
   x16: 0x000000018dba9790  x17: 0x00000001cb2827d0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000018
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000108a583d0  x22: 0x000000028091c640  x23: 0x0000000108a8047f
   x24: 0x0000000000000022  x25: 0x0000000108a7cbf8  x26: 0x00000000c0000000  x27: 0x000000028091c2e0
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016b1499f0   lr: 0x0000000105037ac0
    sp: 0x000000016b149980   pc: 0x0000000105037b30 cpsr: 0x20000000
   esr: 0x9200004f (Data Abort) byte write Permission fault
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your post to clarify what your question is. As it stands, it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: You will need to symbolicate that report in order to find where it's crashing.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to add some clarification. My app is crashing and I am trying to direct my devs to the answer.

Comment: [This Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) shows you how to symbolicate the crash report, but you will need the .`dSYM` file generated for the submitted build.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that the build is created for iOS Deployment Target 13.0. 
device might be running on latest iOS version and you app might not be built for iOS 13.0.

Comment: So you are saying phones can only runs apps where the deployment target == iOS version?

Comment: I mean to say deployment target >= iOS version of the phone.

Comment: The app works fine on my phone - latest software Iohone 8 - the issues seem to only be effecting the XR and EXR or whatever the newest release Iphones are called.